# The garbled issue when using discutils to view the fullname of disc file write in Japanese

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, cjk

The Japanese character and the character after the first dot (where the filename contains two dots) become _ (underline), does it have a solution?

```
Using isoStream As FileStream = New FileStream(curitem, FileMode.Open)
    Dim cd As CDReader = New CDReader(isoStream, True)
    For Each CDentry As DiscUtils.DiscFileInfo In cd.Root.GetFiles()
        Console.WriteLine(CDentry.Name)
        Listbox1.Items.Add(CDentry.FullName.Replace(";1", "").ToLower)
    Next
End Using
```

Examples of garbled filenames:

```
PC環境情報の取得.bat -> *pc______.bat*
hokejyo.pfs.000 -> *hokejyo_.000*
はじめにお読みください.txt -> *________.txt*
```

I am using DiscUtils: [DiscUtils home page](https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils/wiki).

Comment: @邱子恩 It looks like DiscUtils is using the 8.3 format filenames, and I see it looks like it only uses ISO 9660, not Joliet. If the program is only reading from the disc, you could use the [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles) to get the filenames.

Comment: @Andrew Morton,it's cdreader has a joliet argument,type is boolean,if i use the argument,how do I write code?

Comment: @Andrew Morton  how to use Directory.EnumerateFiles to read the file in iso?

Comment: Is it reading from an actual CD or from an ISO image? If it's reading from an image, was that created with the Joliet flag set to True?

Comment: it's reading from a Iso image,and either showing garbled when I set Joliet flag true